# C++ Graph Vertex Coloring Library or Source Code

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Is there a C++ (or any other language) library with a portfolio of algorithms for the problem of [graph coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)?

There are of course naive greedy vertex coloring algorithms, but I'm interested in more interesting algorithms like:

1. Algorithms mentioned in the "Exact Algorithms" section of the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)
2. Approximation algorithms that take advantage of special graph properties like the graph being [planar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) or a [unit disk graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph).
3. Algorithms that find the [fractional coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coloring) of a graph.

That last one is of particular importance to me.

What I found so far is the list on [this page](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/vertex-coloring.shtml) but none of them have any of the above algorithms. Moreover, the best one is [Joe Culberson's Graph Coloring code](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~joe/Coloring) and that was implemented in late 90's, so is very much outdated in terms of not having a documented API (not that this is important for what this question is about, but I thought I'd mention it).

There's the [Koala graph coloring library](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4621641) that has the spirit of what I'm looking for, but if you look at their [source code](http://koalalib.org/wiki/index.php/KoalaWiki) it has not delivered on the promise just yet. It appears to be in very early stages of development.

Other general graph libraries are mentioned in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751826/which-c-graph-library-should-i-use). They include:

1. [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)
2. [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html)
3. [Lemon](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon)
4. [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/introduction.html)
5. [OGDF](http://www.ogdf.net/ogdf.php?id=)

I should note that I use the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html) for a lot of things. In fact, it provides a naive vertex coloring implementation. Joe Culberson's code (mentioned above) does much more.

The following is a list of graph coloring code, I've found (and tested in most cases) but they still mostly fall short in terms of the three algorithm classes above.

1. [GraphCol](http://code.google.com/p/graphcol) - documentation is not in English, sigh.
2. [Planarity](http://code.google.com/p/planarity) - contains a coloring algorithm that guarantees a 5-coloring or better for planar graphs.
3. [Graph-Coloring](http://code.google.com/p/graph-coloring/) - appears to be a re-implementation of a small number of algorithms already implemented by Joe Culberson (above).

Comment: [Koala](https://github.com/krzysztof-turowski/koala-networkit) is still being developed on top of the structures provided by the NetworKit library.

Answer (score 3):

There's some good ones at http://rhydlewis.eu/gcol/. These correspond to a portfolio of algorithms reviewed and tested in my book:

Lewis, R. (2021) *A Guide to Graph Colouring: Algorithms and Applications* (second ed.). Springer. ISBN: 978-3-030-81053-5. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-81054-2

These include greedy, backtracking and metaheuristic approaches. I've included compilation instructions etc. in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can help yourself with the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

Comment: I love BGL, and it does provide one algorithm for vertex coloring, but it's a naive one and Joe Culberson's code (mentioned in the question) does much more. Moreover, BGL certainly doesn't have anything like the three "more interesting" algorithms I mentioned that I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [CXXGraph](https://github.com/ZigRazor/CXXGraph) library. It contains some useful algorithm on Graph

Comment: No coloring, though